# Lookup values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

```
Date        Ticker    Volume
2019-03-21    AAPL        10
2019-03-21    GOOG         5
2019-03-21     IBM         0
2019-03-25    AAPL         0
2019-03-25     IBM         0
2019-03-25    GOOG        12
2019-03-27    AAPL         0
2019-03-27     IBM        16
2019-03-27    GOOG        10
2019-03-28     IBM         9
2019-03-28    GOOG         0
2019-03-28    AAPL        10
```

Suppose the data is ordered by date. How to exact the first row from each date. If the 'Volume' is 0, then take the next row until it's not 0.

```
Date        Ticker    volume
2019-03-21    AAPL        10
2019-03-25    GOOG        12
2019-03-27     IBM        16
2019-03-28     IBM         9
```

I have tried by using lambda, but it seems not working.

```
df_new = df.groupby(['Date']).head(lambda x: 2 if df['Volume'] == 0 else 1).reset_index(0, drop=True)

TypeError: unorderable types: int() < function()
```

If I have enough data and like to exact #2-5 rows (consecutive) from each date. Should I use range function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal and then [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df[df['Volume'].ne(0)].drop_duplicates('Date')
print (df)
         Date Ticker  Volume
0  2019-03-21   AAPL      10
5  2019-03-25   GOOG      12
7  2019-03-27    IBM      16
9  2019-03-28    IBM       9
```

Alterntive with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query('Volume != 0').drop_duplicates('Date')
```

EDIT:

For extract second/third/next columns use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html), only python counts from `0`, so for second rows need `1`, for third `2`:

```
df1 = df[df['Volume'].ne(0)]
print (df1)
          Date Ticker  Volume
0   2019-03-21   AAPL      10
1   2019-03-21   GOOG       5
5   2019-03-25   GOOG      12
7   2019-03-27    IBM      16
8   2019-03-27   GOOG      10
9   2019-03-28    IBM       9
11  2019-03-28   AAPL      10

df2 = df1.groupby('Date').nth(1)
print (df2)
           Ticker  Volume
Date                     
2019-03-21   GOOG       5
2019-03-27   GOOG      10
2019-03-28   AAPL      10
```

Or [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for mask:

```
df2 = df1[df1.groupby('Date').cumcount().eq(1)]
print (df2)
          Date Ticker  Volume
1   2019-03-21   GOOG       5
8   2019-03-27   GOOG      10
11  2019-03-28   AAPL      10
```

Comment: Both worked. All 0 are removed. But drop duplicates only keep the first row of data. How to exact the second/thrid row data.

Comment: Thanks. I realized nth() also accepts list as its parameter. Like `.nth([0, 1, 2])`. Quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
df1=df.loc[df.Volume!=0].drop_duplicates('Date')
Out[13]: 
         Date Ticker  Volume
0  2019-03-21   AAPL      10
5  2019-03-25   GOOG      12
7  2019-03-27    IBM      16
9  2019-03-28    IBM       9
```